# Meteor data isolation

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

How can the isolate subscribtions data between templates?

For example - i have one page with two **different** template:

1) Topic list

2) Popular topics.

I have two **different** Meteor.publish and Subscribtions for this.

1) In Topic-list template i have sorted by CreatedAt-field.

```
Meteor.subscribe('topics');

  Template.topics_main.helpers({
        topics:function(){
            return Topic.find({},{sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        }
  });
```

2) In Popular list i sort data by Rating-field.

```
    Meteor.subscribe('popularTopics');
    Template.top_topics.helpers({
          topics:function(){
               return Topic.find({}, {
           sort: {
               views: -1
           },
           limit: 5
       });

   }
});
```

And when i will scroll my Topic-list, i will get data from Popular Topics. This is not good:) How can i isolate data bweetwen two templates with diferent subscribtions, but one type of collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observeChanges) might be what you need. It allows you to publish your documents to a specific collection, so you could have your two publications (`topics` and `popularTopics`) grabbing data from the same collection on the server (`Topics`), but sending it to different collections on the client (e.g. `Topics` and `PopularTopics`).

Here's an example:

```
// globally somewhere
const Topics = new Mongo.Collection('topics');
const PopularTopics = new Mongo.Collection('populartopics');
```

Add your publications, with observeChanges sending the published documents to two different collections on the client:

```
// topics.publications.js 
const abstractPublish = function (collectionName, query) {
  const cursor = Topics.find(query);

  const cursorHandle = cursor.observeChanges({
    added(id, fields) {
      this.added(collectionName, id, fields);
    },
    changed(id, fields) {
      this.changed(collectionName, id, fields);
    },
    removed(id) {
      this.removed(collectionName, id);
    }
  });

  this.onStop(()=>{
    if (cursorHandle) cursorHandle.stop();
  });

  this.ready();
};

Meteor.publish('topics', function () {
  // set up a publication to the "topics" collection
  abstractPublish.call(this, 'topics', {});
});

Meteor.publish('popularTopics', function () {
  // set up a publication to the "populartopics" collection
  abstractPublish.call(this, 'populartopics', {popular: true});
});
```

Then set up your template-level subscriptions:

```
// topics_main.js
Template.topics_main.onCreated(function () {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('topics', function () {
      Topics.find().fetch(); // returns all topics
    );
  });
});
```

And in your popular topics template:

```
// top_topics.js
Template.top_topics.onCreated(function () {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('popularTopics', function () {
      PopularTopics.find().fetch(); // returns only topics that have {popular: true}
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for awesome answer! The problem in this case its my ORM:)
I use Astronomy. It will a litle bit harder to use your method via Astronomy:) But, this decision looks pretty good:)


Really Meteor does not have solutions isolation  on a  template level?

Comment: If you can't see both templates at the same time (e.g. if they are on different pages of your app) then using a template-level subscription should be good enough. Because when you render top_topics, Topic only contains the popular topics, then when that template is destroyed, the subscription is stopped and the documents are deleted from the client. Then you can render topics_main, and Topic will get filled with all the documents (popular and unpopular).

Comment: Yep, i know about different pages:)
The problem is they stored in one page. And, im just trying to find a correct way, without hax. So, its look like no way without hack)

Full problem with images: https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-can-we-isolate-subscribtions-data/28062/3

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of the Meteor's current publication model.

Some options that come to mind to overcome this:

1. Find a way to differentiate the data using a more refined query.
2. Fetch some of the data in another way (e.g, using a method, without using pub/sub or the collections).
3. Publish to a "virtual" collection (by manually monitoring the cursor in the publication).

The [Apollo Stack](http://www.apollostack.com/) may also be handy.